# How to combine the output of regex and print in perl?

Tags: perl

Hi I have search result as,

```
"abc"
```

from

```
perl -lne 'print for /"name":"(.+?)"/g' file > newfile
```

and

```
"def"
```

from

```
perl -lne 'print for /"title":"(.+?)"/g' file > newfile
```

I'm trying to get the O/p as

```
abc:"def",
```

by combining both one liners. I tried with:

```
perl -lne 'print for /"name":"(.+?)","title":"(.+?)"/g' *.json > newfile11
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Want to edit your question with an example input file?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured this out based on the input from your other question.

I'm assuming you have this as input:

```
{"card":{"cardName":"10AN10G","portSignalRates":["10AN10G-1-OTU2","10AN10G-1-OTU2E","10AN10G-1-TENGIGE","10AN10G-1-STM64"],"listOfPort":{"10AN10G-1-OTU2":{"portAid":"10AN10G-1-OTU2","signalType":"OTU2","tabNames":["PortDetails"],"requestType":{"PortDetails":"PTP"},"paramDetailsMap":{"PortDetails":[{"type":"dijit.form.TextBox","name":"signalType","title":"Signal Rate","id":"","options":[],"label":"","value":"OTU2","checked":"","enabled":"false","selected":""},{"type":"dijit.form.TextBox","name":"userLabel","title":"Description","id":"","options":[],"label":"","value":"","checked":"","enabled":"true","selected":""},{"type":"dijit.form.Select","name":"Frequency","title":"Transmit Frequency",}}}}}}
```

or at least a large text file containing those types of lines. You want to parse out the name and title from each line. You can do that with this one line.

```
Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/12
$ perl -ne 'if ( /"name":"([^"]+)","title":"([^"]+?)"/ ) { print $1 . ":\"" . $2 . "\",\n" }' input2.txt
```

which outputs:

```
signalType:"Signal Rate",
```

It works by capturing 2 group in the regex, one for the title and one for the name. The `-ne` flags go through each line the file and execute the code between the single quotes. `$1` and `$2` are the group we captured, and they are printed at the end.

Just as a tip, it is much easier to help you if you post your input, expected output, errors you ran into, and code you've tried when asking question.

---

**edit:** just wanted to put a disclaimer that it is better to parse JSON with a module, because what if you have escaped `"` with in a title or name? This regex wouldn't pick it up, but JSON parsers can handle those types of cases for you.